# Elixir GenStage scaling depending on load

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to build a following pipeline:
`[A] -> [B] -> [C]`

`A` takes entries from database which have timestamp older than one day.

`B` performs some heavy task using external node.

`C` stores result of computation back to DB.

Each B-node can perform more than one task concurrently, and we can set the level of concurrency on node spawn.

What I want is to spawn as many B-nodes as needed depending on how many tasks are waiting in DB.

Is GenStage a good fit for that task or better to build something with queue and bunch of GenServers that talk to each other? How to approach it? Custom dispatcher, that not only distributes tasks, but also spawns B-nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to spawn as many B-nodes as needed depending on how many tasks are waiting in DB.

In this particular case, neither `GenStage` nor any `Queue` is required. `GenStage` is solving an exactly opposite task: it helps when you want to spawn *at most `N`* B-nodes, despite how many tasks are waiting and keep this value more or less constant.

I would implement what you need explicitly: just load all the waiting tasks from the database and [`Stream.map/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Stream.html#map/2) them to `GenServer`’s instances.

These `GenServer`s should be responsible for running long task and storing the result into the database afterward. Then they silently die.

Comment: But you could technically use GenStage here without any issue and still solve the problem, or am I missing something?

Have your max/min demands change based on the length of the entries. 

You got 1000 entries, but 50 workers, you could double your workers but still keep a limit?

Comment: @Seivan I am not sure I follow. Since you do not know in advance how many items to demand, GenStage would mostly hinder here.

Comment: he initial demand, no, you're right there. However after the initial demand, you could launch additional [B] and the same is true for the reverse; where you could shut down [B] if there isn't enough demand. This is probably stupid and mostly because I haven't grasped GenStage 100% but I create entire new pipes for higher demand where each pipe does 1 demand at a time. It's a bit easier to have a mental model in this shape although with an overhead.

Comment: @Seivan why create pipes for demands instead of just spawning new processes? Processes are almost costless in erlang vm. I do not get why does your scenario needs a GenStage at all.

Comment: GenStage makes it easier to manage failures and persistence. All jobs are are persisted and then processed through pipes of various ProducerConsumers and Consumers.